# Why is CodeIgniter adding an extra "where" to my delete query?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause

For some reason, CodeIgniter is adding an extra "where" clause to my delete query.  It's obvious as to why the MySQL error is happening... but why is CI adding this extra clause?

This is the error:

```
Unknown column '8' in 'where clause'
DELETE FROM `forum_messages` WHERE `thread_id` = '8' AND `8` IS NULL
```

This is my code:

```
function delete($thread_id){

    $this->db->save_queries = FALSE;

    $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
    if(!$this->db->delete('forum_messages')){

        $this->error = "The messages in this thread could not be deleted because of a database error: ".$this->db->_error_message();

    } else {

        $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
        if(!$this->db->delete('forum_threads')){

            $this->error = "The thread could not be deleted because of a database error: ".$this->db->_error_message();

        }

    }


}
```

UPDATE:

None of the answers suggested below worked.  For some reason I had to switch the delete queries and delete from forum_messages before I deleted before forum_threads.

Comment: you are adding twice. above if condition and in else part

Answer (score 0):

You have one extra where condition in your `else` condition. Now check this.

```
  function delete($thread_id){

            $this->db->save_queries = FALSE;

            $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
            if(!$this->db->delete('forum_threads')){

                $this->error = "The thread could not be deleted because of a database error: ".$this->db->_error_message();

            } else {
                if(!$this->db->delete('forum_messages')){

                    $this->error = "The messages in this thread could not be deleted because of a database error: ".$this->db->_error_message();

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: sorry, i thought i added that in my original question... i have updated it.

Comment: can you please tell me what does $thread_id variable contains.

Comment: $thread_id should be like
$thread_id = array('field1' => 'val1', 'field2' => 'val2');

Comment: if you look in the error message/query, thread_id is passed correctly since it is equal to 8.

Comment: I think you are passing 8 as column value as well.
Unknown column '8' in 'where clause'

Comment: Yes, the question is why is " AND 8 IS NULL" being added to the query.

Comment: Something wrong with data in $thread_id array. Please do print_r($thread_id); at the starting of the function. :)

Comment: The variable $thread_id is not an array.  It is a single int.  In the case of the error from my original question, it is "8".  So therefore, the data in $thread_id is indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra `$this->db->where('thread_id',$thread_id)` in the else statement

Try this:

```
function delete($thread_id){
        $this->db->save_queries = FALSE;
        $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
        if(!$this->db->delete('forum_threads')){
            $this->error = "The thread could not be deleted because of a database error: ".$this->db->_error_message();
        } else {
            if(!$this->db->delete('forum_messages')){
                $this->error = "The messages in this thread could not be deleted because of a database error: ".$this->db->_error_message();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why was this given -1??

Comment: Why would I remove the where clause from the forum_threads table?

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't actually read the script properly, just found the error and removed it, I'll change it right now... Kindly, take back that -1 :(

Comment: Sure, doesn't mean that I'm going to accept your answer, though. :D

Comment: Its okay, I think this will work. Still check it out and tell me :)